# Date cast to int - why is it wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, type-conversion

I've got a question. Why does date CAST to int doesn't work while varchar to int works fine? e.g.

If we declare a variable and run this query it won't work,

```
declare @dateb datetime
set @dateb = getdate()

select cast(@dateb as int)
```

while this query will work fine. Why?

```
select cast(convert(varchar(8),@dateb,112) as int)
```

> date should be 8 numbers.

Comment: well if it did work, what would be the result?  What is the int value of today?

Comment: what version of SQL server ?  It worked here in sql2014 - I got 43348, the number of days since 12/31/1899 possibly - I believe you can't do that with type Date though (possibly to stop poor practices) - yes you can not do it with Date and DateTime2 - they are newer types, and the designers probably wanted to stop the use of arithmetic instead of DateAdd for readability/quality reasons.

Comment: `43348` for `int` at sql'12

Comment: 43348 is right result? I don't understand how it's connected to today's date which is 2018-09-06

Comment: select DATEADD(day,-43348,getdate()) so if that was day ZERO, what would Day 1 be?  The value you got is the number of days since the last day of the 1800's (1899-12-31) - you can compare that to spread-sheets such as excel, lotus 123 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue comes from a misunderstanding about how SQL Server stores date information. It isn't stored as a readable date, but rather as an integer, or series of integers, that the engine uses to calculate the date in question, and then display in a human friendly way.

The `CONVERT` function you used above creates a text representation of the date as you're expecting to see it, then converts that representation to an integer (also as you're expecting to see it). The straight conversion from a date data type shows you the integer that SQL Server actually uses to store "today", but that's not what you're expecting.

There's a really good article about it on [Robert Sheldon's blog](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-sql-server-dates-and-times-horribly-wrong/#first) if you're interested in going into more depth.